# How to fill a data frame with cumulative sum with missing values in another variable

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

Imagine you have the following data frame

```
x<- c(3, 5, 9, 12, 14)
y<- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 1.4, 1.8)
df<- data.frame(x, y)
df
```

[image]

I asked a few months ago, how to fill "x" with remaining numbers and those numbers take the value zero in "y".
And the answer was:

```
df <- tidyr::complete(df, x = 0:16, fill = list(y = 0))
cbind(df$x, df$y)
```

[image]

Now, I'd like to fill the numbers in the following way, but automatically, and I don't know if it is possible.
How to obtein "y1" automatically

Thanks in advance.

```
df$y1<- c(0,0,0, 0.2,0.2, 0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4, 0.7,0.7,0.7, 1.4,1.4, 1.8,1.8,1.8)
cbind(df$x, df$y1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the `fill` in `complete`, leave it as it is, so that by default it gets filled by `NA`, then use `fill` from `tidyr` to update the NA elements with the previous non-NA

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tidyr::complete(df, x = 0:16) %>%
   fill(y, .direction = "down") %>% 
   mutate(y = replace(y, is.na(y), 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 17 × 2
       x     y
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0   0  
 2     1   0  
 3     2   0  
 4     3   0.2
 5     4   0.2
 6     5   0.4
 7     6   0.4
 8     7   0.4
 9     8   0.4
10     9   0.7
11    10   0.7
12    11   0.7
13    12   1.4
14    13   1.4
15    14   1.8
16    15   1.8
17    16   1.8
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It work´s perfectly.  Is it possible to specify "x" from 0 to 16 by 0.5 (0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2 an so on). Thank you very much

Comment: @MiguelAngelArnau use `seq` i.e. `x = seq(0, 16, by = 0.5)`

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
 complete(x=0:16) %>%
 fill(y) %>%
 replace_na(list(y=0))

# A tibble: 17 x 2
       x     y
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0   0  
 2     1   0  
 3     2   0  
 4     3   0.2
 5     4   0.2
 6     5   0.4
 7     6   0.4
 8     7   0.4
 9     8   0.4
10     9   0.7
11    10   0.7
12    11   0.7
13    12   1.4
14    13   1.4
15    14   1.8
16    15   1.8
17    16   1.8
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It work´s perfectly. How can incorporate the result in the data frame, and is it possible to specify "x" from 0 to 16 by 0.5 (0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2 an so on). Thank you very much

Comment: @MiguelAngelArnau do `complete(x = seq(0, 16, 0.5))`. Also the results is in the dataframe already. Unless you mean to save it

Comment: I'd like to save it as a new data frame ...

Comment: It's clear.      df<- tidyr::complete(df, x=0:16) %>%   fill(y) %>%   replace_na(list(y=0)).  Thank you very much for your help